How does determinism or eternal existence affect how “lucky” something is?
Suppose I have a dice with 1 million sides. I then think of a number, say, 700,000. Assume that there is no rigging involved.
The dice then lands on 700,000. Let’s assume we live in a world where this dice roll is not deterministic. In other words, let’s treat this as some quantum sort of event that is truly and inherently not determined with each outcome being as equally probable.
Now, if it lands on that number, clearly this would be considered a remarkable feat of luck. One might even put a number on the chances of this: 1 in a million.
But now let’s suppose the same scenario but assume that we live in a deterministic world. In other words, the initial conditions and the laws of the universe just happened to exist in a way where the dice roll could only have landed on 700,000 and nowhere else along with me thinking of 700,000 and nothing else. Technically, the “physical” probability of anything undetermined is 0. Thus, the “physical probability” of anything except 700,000 would be 0 before I even roll the dice (unlike the first scenario). But one can perhaps still give this an “epistemic” probability of 1 in a million. Is this scenario more, less, or about as equally “lucky” as the first?
Let’s make the scenario even more interesting. Let’s assume that we were in a past eternal universe. In other words, the laws and initial conditions were simply always set up this way eternally. They never actually “started”. What then now? Would laws and initial conditions being set up to exist eternally to eventually create that dice roll be just as lucky as the previous two scenarios? Or no?

Huh? And random bold text?

Fun question. I think it depends how you define "lucky", and I'm inclined to think that a solution would involve different types of luck, such as what you eluded to, like an "epistemic" luck and an "objective" luck, whatever those things may mean.

@DikranMarsupial I don’t think you understand the question. Posting this same question on other philosophy avenues seems to get more positive attention. Hence it seems as if people on this site just aren’t philosophically sophisticated

Does this answer your question? Isn’t everything absurdly improbable?

@DikranMarsupial Well there are different interpretations of probability. If something is determined, it could be the only way that it is. But even if everything was determined, it would still make sense to call the probability of a dice roll landing on 6 1/6, atleast to some people. You said that if something can be a certain way, the probability of everything else is 0. So that contradicts the notion of epistemic probability

I’m not sure what the inverse gambler’s fallacy charge has anything to do with this. And why do you guys keep talking about multiple accounts?

@DikranMarsupial your comments are vague, not the answer. “ Epistemic probability depends on your state of knowledge, so it is different depending on whether you make it conditional or not.” Meaningless sentence

We use probabilities to quantify our uncertainty about the future. That is unrelated to whether the future is actually uncertain or not. The deterministic world and undeterministic world are not different in whether people with limited knowledge of the future consider events probable or improbable.
To take an analogy from computer science: You can treat a Pseudo random number generator as truly random as long as you can't predict it. It most certainly is not, but if you can't distinguish between the two, then it doesn't really matter that one isn't "truly random".
Similarly, in the deterministic universe there is only a difference to the undeterministic universe if the people therein can actually predict the future.
